# Make text go outside div

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="popupLeft">
    <h1 class="popupTittel">Title goes here</h1>
</div>
```

I want this text go outside the div popupLeft, but only for xx pixles. Is that possible?

Perhaps I did not explain well enough.

There are two "modes" on my website. If the content is supposed to draw a gallery I have the title, intro-text and content-text in a div called 'popupLeft' and a gallery in the 'popupRight'.

But if there is no gallery, is is supposed to be text in both the divs, and I want the title to stretch all the way from the left-div and the right-div. The right and left-div are positioned side by side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add it position:relative

ie. to get it 10 px above, do this:

```
.popupTittel {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

if you want to move it right outside the div, add position:absolute like this

```
#popupLeft {
  position: relative;
}
.popupTittel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like in `margin-top: -10px;` or similar? You should consider reading a CSS guide, since this is very elemental stuff.

Comment: This creates a scrollbar in my div.

Answer (score 0):

Id actually use position:relative; top:-10; as that will keep all elements below that objects margins correct...

Example here :)

http://jsfiddle.net/r2bp9/

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain well enough.

There are two "modes" on my website. If the content is supposed to draw a gallery I have the title, intro-text and content-text in a div called 'popupLeft' and a gallery in the 'popupRight'.

But if there is no gallery, is is supposed to be text in both the divs, and I want the title to stretch all the way from the left-div and the right-div. The right and left-div are positioned side by side.